# Receiving undefined when trying to set return value of await function as a constant

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm trying to set a constant to an await function to get the return information from getInfo. I can console long the object before returning it. But when I try to console log the value in post I get undefined. What am I doing wrong?

```
router.post('/', function(req,res,next) {
    (async function(){
        const modifierInfo = await getInfo();
            console.log("returns undefined", modifierInfo)
            //do more with return info after
    })().catch(next)
});

const getInfo = () => {
    (async function(){
        try {
            const ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(pool);
            const statement = await ps.prepare("selectQuery");
            const result = await statement.execute();
            const modifierInfo = await result.recordset[0];
            await statement.unprepare();
            console.log("returns object", modifierInfo)
            return modifierInfo;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })()
};
```

Comment: What happens when you try to set it to a let instead of a const?

Comment: Tried let modifierInfo = await getModifierGroupInfo still undefined when I console.log it

Comment: if you define your functions (and your route for that matter) as async, you don't need to wrap them in self-executing anonymous funcs. I am guessing `getModifierGroupInfo` is actually supposed to be `getInfo`, is that correct or no?

Comment: Where is getModifierGroupInfo defined?  All I see is a getI go.

Comment: Sorry getModifierGroupInfo is supposed to be getInfo thanks @HolyMoly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that `getInfo` itself needs to by async. try something like this:

```
router.post('/', async (req,res,next) => {
    try {
        const modifierInfo = await getInfo(req.body.groupID);
        console.log(modifierInfo)
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
});

async function getInfo(groupID) {
    try {
        const ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(pool);
        const statement = await ps.prepare("selectQuery");
        const result = await statement.execute();
        const modifierInfo = await result.recordset[0];
        await statement.unprepare();
        console.log("returns object", modifierInfo)
        return modifierInfo;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
};
```

Comment: happy to help, async/await was tricky for me at first too....still is sometimes ;)